# While deleting vm in Azure, last status that I get is 'Deleting' and that too in provisioningState field. How to get 'Deleted' status?

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-api-management, azure-java-sdk, azure-resource-group

I am using Java api (azure-compute:version 0.9.0) to perform VM operation. I want to make sure cloud operation on VM is performed successfully. I am getting some issue in Delete operation.

- While beginDeleting(async) VM, I get Future and
  status in DeleteOperationResponse is Error once I get the response
  after future is Done.
- Later after submitting beginDeleting(async), I am getting VM from VMGetResponse and then checking provisioningState after every 1 sec. After several 'Deleting', I get 'Error' state.

My expectation is to get VM object even after termination of instance with status like Deleted(or terminated) as I get in Amazon. So that I can get assured my cloud operation is successful.

Comment: (1) why you are getting an error while deleting - please provide detailed error message. you can always look the at resource logs via the portal.  (2) do not expect to get a VM object after it was deleted. you can look at the resource group's logs to see previous operations

Comment: Any way to get last n number of logs from java api or *OperationResponse object of last n operations. Can you suggest any good documentation or architecture flow diagram for azure java api.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any APIs call of Azure SDK for Java are really calling the related Azure REST APIs. So according to the references of REST API [Delete a virtual machine](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/compute/virtualmachines/virtualmachines-delete) & [Get information about a virtual machine](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/compute/virtualmachines/virtualmachines-get), you only could get the error status which comes from the response `404` status code, as below, because the resource has been deleted.

1. Quote from the description of [`Response`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/compute/virtualmachines/virtualmachines-delete#response) of `Delete a virtual machine`.

   > If resource does not exist, 404 (NotFound) is returned.
2. Quote from the description of [`Response`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/compute/virtualmachines/virtualmachines-get#response) of `Get information about a virtual machine`.

   > otherwise 404 (Not Found) is returned.

For your question in the comment, if you want to get the last `n` number of logs, the only way is using [Azure Monitor REST API in Java](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/monitor/). On Azure Offical website, you can refer to the documents below to know Azure Monitor service.

1. [Audit Logs in Azure Preview Portal](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/updates/audit-logs-in-azure-preview-portal/)
2. [Get started with Azure Monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/monitoring-and-diagnostics/monitoring-get-started)
3. [View events and activity logs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/monitoring-and-diagnostics/insights-debugging-with-events)